# How to Save Large Json Data?

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net, jsonconvert

i have a large ObservableCollection that I want to get out as Json file.
I used the following code, But I get an error `out of memory`

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content, Formatting.Indented);
await File.WriteAllTextAsync("file.json");
```

How can I save this huge ObservableCollection in a json file?

Comment: Something to think about:  Is the consumer of this file also also going to have problems when it tries to load it?

Comment: @Wyck no i dont need to load it, i only want to save it.

Comment: `WriteAllTextAsync` takes (at least) two arguments.  Your example is missing the text to be written.  You probably meant `WriteAllTextAsync("file.json", json)`

Comment: If you don't need to load it, ever, just do `File.WriteAllBytes("file.json", new byte[0]);`. It'll be empty, but since you don't need to load it, the contents shouldn't matter, so you can save some disk space in the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of serializing to a string, and then writing the string to a stream, stream it directly:

```
using var stream = File.Create("file.json");
JsonSerializer.Serialize(stream, content, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIdented = true 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try to serialize directly to the file.This way Newtosoft https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializewithjsonserializertofile.htm recomends to do it

```
using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(@"c:\file.json"))
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        serializer.Serialize(file, content);
    }
```